# How to access the Android browser settings via code

Tags: android, browser

Is there a way to access and alter the settings of the standard Android browser programmatically?

Comment: Do you mean if you are using it as part of your app?

Comment: No, I want to edit the settings independently from my app. I like to change the standard settings like the user agent or text size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume not, unless you can set up a shared user id with the browser (ie, you are the system vendor), you have rooted the phone, the browser happens to expose a mechanism through intents (don't think so), or its possible to do via javascript and you use an intent to send the browser to a local file containing that script (which it probably isn't, unless by a mistake in the browser).

You can make your own browser though, either utilizing the webkit engine or not.