# How to open Default Browser settings from my android application?

Tags: android, settings

As per my requirement I have to clear default browser cache from my application. I want to open browser settings from my application, so that user can clear the cache.
By using following code.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS), 0);
```

I'm able to open all manage applications. Is there any way to open browser settings directly?

Thanks

Comment: Which browser? There is no single browser for Android. Different devices will ship with different browser apps (e.g., the Nexus 7 ships with Chrome).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035410/how-to-access-the-android-browser-settings-via-code

Comment: Am asking about android's default browser only.

Answer (score 0):

Settings of an application is stored in Shared Preferances of the application and each application has different directories to store it by default. For your internet browser the settings are stored in "data/data/com.android.browser/shared-prefs/" direcory. There is a XML file named as "com.android.browser_preferences.xml" that has these settings. Access this file by shared prefs and make changes.
Code.

```
String path = "data/data/com.android.browser/shared-prefs/";
String file = "com.android.browser_preferences.xml";
SharedPreferances setting = getSharedPreferances(path+file, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
SharedPreferances.editor edit = setting.edit();
```

Comment: You can also see database and cache of browser too

Comment: I dont want to change browser settings from my application. By clicking on a button user should go to browser settings. then he can clear the cache.